# How do I sync a git repository to subversion?

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

We use several open source libraries that are hosted on github. I want to be able to clone the git repositories and basically push them into our local subversion repository so I can start a CI build internally for them.

How do I set up the connection to the svn server in a git repository that I cloned from github? I understand how to clone out of subversion.. but how do I push a new project into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to install svn as well as git, unfortunately.

1. In svn: Create the initial svn repository with a minor initial commit, e.g. of a README.
2. In git: Create a remote branch in git corresponding to that svn repo.
3. Create a tracking branch for that svn branch as if the svn repo were your source.
4. Rebase your git commits from your master branch onto the tracking branch.
5. `git svn dcommit` (to send the new commits in the branch into svn)

The git-svn bridge doesn't cover all the edge cases, like pushing a git repo to an svn one or adding svn ignore properties, so sometimes you end up having to work with a svn repo copy directly in addition to the git-svn, I've found.